# porque php envia registros duplicados a phpMyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, adobe-flash

He hecho un chat con Flash AS3 i php y tengo una bd de Hostinger

El chat funciona bien pero envia o recibe registros duplicados al apretar el boton Envia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir cuando aprieto el boton envia como pueden ver en la imagen, salen dos id distintas para el mismo mensaje.

Aquí debajo les dejo el codigo php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

submitScoreProvaMar.php

```html
<?php

$user = 'u640465832_mar';
$pass = 'xxxxxxxx';
$dbName = 'u640465832_usuar';

$mysqli = new mysqli('mysql.hostinger.es', $user, $pass, $dbName);

if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
 echo "Failed to connect: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$user  = $_POST['user'];
$missatge  = $_POST['missatge'];

$query  = "INSERT INTO provaMar (User, Missatge) VALUES ('" . $user . "', '" . $missatge . "')";

$mysqli->query($query);

$result   = $mysqli->query($query);
$returnValue  = $result->num_rows;

$mysqli->close();

echo $returnValue;

?>
```

getScoresProvaMar.php

```html
<?php

$user = 'u640465832_mar';
$pass = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$dbName = 'u640465832_usuar';

$mysqli = new mysqli('mysql.hostinger.es', $user, $pass, $dbName);

if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
 echo "Failed to connect: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}


$query = 'SELECT * FROM provaMar ORDER by Datetime DESC limit 10';

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$returnString = '';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
 $returnString .= ($row['Datetime'] . "\n");
 $returnString .= ($row['User'] . ' diu: ' .$row['Missatge']. "\n");

}

echo "returnString=" .$returnString;


?>
```

y el código AS3 en Flash

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me deja publicar codigo flash . Codigo Flash AS3

Si alguien sabe porque lo envía duplicado me hará un favor
Muy agradecida

Comment: Bienvenido/a a Stackoverflow. Por favor, cambia todas las imágenes por cada texto del código, las imágenes son difíciles de analizar para detectar posibles errores. Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/164499/edit) para hacer esos cambios. Ten esto en cuenta para futuras preguntas. Gracias.

Comment: Ya he puesto el codigo pero el AS3 no me dejó

Comment: No lo pongas como fragmentos de código (code snippet), sino como texto plano, copiando y pegando... o sea, muy sencillo, copias el texto del código, lo pegas, seleccionas todo el bloque de código de nuevo y con él seleccionado presionas en la imagen **`{}`**, para que quede identado. Los fragmentos de código sólo son útiles para código HTML/CSS/Javascript que se pueda probar aquí, para otras cosas no hacen más que entorpecer, no sé si me explico.

Answer (score 3):

Porque en tu tercera captura, haces uso de `query()` dos veces.

```
$mysqli->query($query);//ejecuta insert, éste no hace falta

$result = $mysqli->query($query);//ejecuta insert
```

Ejecutando [query()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

> Realiza una consulta a la base de datos.

Como lo ejecutas dos veces, haces el insert dos veces.

Comment: Ah, vale, provaré

Comment: Geniaaaaaaaal, muchísimas y más que muchísimas gracias!!!!

Comment: como marco la respuesta como correcta?

Comment: disculpa por mi torpeza, no lo veo. Sale la foto de perfil, el nombre y unos números

Comment: valeeeee, gracias